# How to keep ES6 syntax when transpiling with Typescript

Tags: typescript

I hope I am not missing a point here.
But how can I keep ES6 syntax when transpiling to JS.
For instance, if I code:

```
class Person {
  public name: string;
  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
let person = new Person('John Doe');
console.log(person.name);
```

TS gives me: (*"target": "es6" in tsconfig.json*)

```
var Person = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Person(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    return Person;
}());
var person = new Person('John Doe');
console.log(person.name);
```

But I want TS to give me:

```
class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  } 
}
let person = new Person('John Doe');
console.log(person.name);
```

My tsconfig.json is like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true
  }
}
```

P.S.: If I run the command:

```
tsc -t es6 app.ts
```

It works;

Comment: How are you doing your transpiling?

Comment: `"target": "es6"` should work afaik but you can also try `"target": "es2015"` which is the official name of ES6. In any case it seems like your target is not properly set or being picked up by the compiler.

Comment: @PietroNadalini I have a tsconfig.json with "{"compilerOptions":{"target":"es6"}}".

Comment: @AaronBeall I have changed to es2015 by it keeps transpiling from class Person to var Person = /** @class*/

Comment: Please edit your question and add the whole content of your `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: The compiler is obviously just not loading the config file, or the file is broken. That's the problem you need to be solving.

Comment: you want to set the `target` and `module`

Comment: @Paleo I've edit the content and add the configs.

Answer (score 2):

Your file `tsconfig.json` is ignored when you specify `app.ts` in the command line.

In `tsconfig.json`, add a section `exclude` after the compiler options:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Then, just run: `tsc`.

See also [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html):

> #### Using tsconfig.json
>
> - By invoking tsc **with no input files** […]
> - By invoking tsc **with no input files** and a `--project` (or just `-p`) command line option […]

Comment: Yep! That solved and he output is ES6 as desired. Thanks!