# TypeScript. How prevent transpiling while using ESNext as a target in tsconfig.json?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've already found that question and believe it should help: [How to keep ES6 syntax when transpiling with Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56808741/how-to-keep-es6-syntax-when-transpiling-with-typescript) , but without any luck... It's a bit different.

In my case, while `yarn tsc --project tsconfig.json` the file with:

```
// ./index.tsx

class Person {
  public name: string;
  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  _run = () => {
    console.log('I\'m running!')
  }
}
let person = new Person('John Doe');
console.log(person.name);
```

became like:

```
// ./index.js

class Person {
    constructor(name) {
        this._run = () => {
            console.log('I\'m running!');
        };
        this.name = name;
    }
}
let person = new Person('John Doe');
console.log(person.name);
```

**Eventually, how can I get the same code as I have thrown on the input? E.g. without any postprocessing.**

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": false,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "target": "ESNext", 
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "types": ["node"],
    "lib": ["dom", "es6", "es2017", "es2018", "es2019", "es2020","esnext"]
  },
  "linebreak-style": [true, "LF"],
  "typeAcquisition": {
    "enable": true
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.test.ts",
    "**/*.test.tsx",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `index.tsx` be in the exclude list?

Comment: Can you give any more background on what you're trying to achieve with this? There might be an alternative approach to it.

Comment: @Sly_cardinal well, while developing locally I don't need any kind of code translating. Just to be converted from TS to JS for regular debug inside the browser. That's the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enabling [`useDefineForClassFields`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) in `tsconfig.json` will generate JavaScript code that is more similar to your TypeScript source:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "useDefineForClassFields": true
  }
}
```

Using your example:

```
// ./index.tsx

class Person {
  public name: string;
  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  _run = () => {
    console.log('I\'m running!')
  }
}
let person = new Person('John Doe');
console.log(person.name);
```

will be transpiled to:

```
// index.js
"use strict";
class Person {
    name;
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    _run = () => {
        console.log('I\'m running!');
    };
}
let person = new Person('John Doe');
console.log(person.name);
```

Comment: Yeah, it works almost as I needed, btw some parts are still transpiled. Example in case if we use React. Look: `_run = () => { return (React.createElement("div", null)); }` instead of `_run () => { return <div /> }`

Comment: In `tsconfig.json` set `"jsx": "preserve"` to keep your jsx as-written

Comment: Thanks, but it seems not working along with `ts-loader`. Seems like I'll need to think a way of `babel-loader`